# How to submit React JS PWA to stores?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs

Is it possible or allowed to publish a webview including the URI to a mobile-optimized PWA (written in react) to Google's Play Store and Apple's App Store? Are there any good instructions for this, you can hardly find anything about this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, for Google. There is a nice intro walkthrough, https://developers.google.com/codelabs/pwa-in-play#0.

Not sure for App Store, maybe has changed, some articles refer to a pwabuilder, which provides a service https://medium.com/@diballesteros/how-to-publish-a-pwa-to-the-ios-app-store-20c9fd528ba9